# Some questions about linear systems with random variable.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

The linear system: $Ax=b$

I know that if the system is underdetermined, there will be closed-form solutions. But if $b\sim any~distribution$, are there closed-form solutions?

More detailedly, this is what I am trying to solve:
$$
\arg \min_x \lVert x - X\rVert_2, X\sim any~distribution, X, x \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}
$$
The situation above is exactly a linear system with random variables:
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}1&1&...&1 \end{pmatrix}\\
x = \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\...\\x_n \end{pmatrix}~~
b = \begin{pmatrix}X_1\\X_2\\...\\X_n \end{pmatrix}\\
$$

Moreover, are there any recommended materials for studying these cases(linear algebra + probability theory)? I am an undergraduate student majoring in computer science, and although I have taken these two courses, I'm still unable to combine them.

Comment: Can't you take $x=X$ ? Maybe there is an expectation missing.

Comment: @P.Quinton Thanks for your comments. You're right. It's my bad that an expectation is missing. $x$ should not be a random variable. I mean, given a specific distribution, for example, normal distribution, can we represent $x$ with the properties of the distribution, e.g., variance and mean?

Comment: Can you fix the minimization ? It is still unclear what you want. Is it $\operatorname{argmin}_x \mathbb E[\| x -X \|^2]$ ?

Comment: @P.Quinton, I'm sorry for not replying to you for so long because I'm too busy these days. I finally found out $x-X$ is still a random variable and you are right. I think the answer is the mean of $X$. I really need to brush up on probability theory. lmao :-)